# Python Requests: request stops working when an f string is used in the URL

Tags: python, python-requests, get

I am trying to make a POST request, pull a variable from the response, and pass that variable into a GET request using python requests lib.

My problem is when I use an f string to pass that variable into the 2nd request, I receive a 500 response from the server. However, if I manually copy/paste the variable into the second request and run the program again (not using an f string), I get my 200 response and get the data I need.

Here's what I mean:

```
        #First request:
        REQ = 'http://myURL.com/post-request'
        r = requests.post(REQ, headers=headers, data=data)
        #this returns a 200 response with my unique ID which I need to pass into the next request
    
        response = r.json() #convert it to json
        myId = response['uniqueId'] #let's say the ID is 12345
    
        REQ2 = f'http://myURL.com/get-request?uniqueId={myId}'
        r2 = requests.get(REQ2, headers=headers)
        #^this request returns a 500 response
    
        #However, If I make that same request again and just type my id 12345 directly into the url:
        REQ2 = 'http://myURL.com/get-request?uniqueId=12345'
        r2 = requests.get(REQ2, headers=headers)
        #I get a 200 response with the data I need.
```

I have also made sure the URL in both of these requests is actually a string, and I've tested to make sure `r2.url == REQ2` is `True`. I can't figure out why it doesn't work when I use the f string.

I've also tried passing the variable using "params=" in my get request, as the Requests documentation suggests, but it didn't make a difference. I also tried using a .format string instead and still no luck.

Comment: Don't use `id` for a variable name, as it shadows a builtin -- what is the type of that variable?

Comment: Good point. I changed it to myId but I'm getting the same result. It is a str.

Comment: Easy to debug - instead of passing the URLs as a string literal, store the strings as variables and then compare them.

Comment: Thank you but I think this is actually how I attempted it, I just changed it on this post for brevity. I'll go back and edit the post to what it actually is.
I changed it back. Let me know if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

U wrote u compare
`r2.url == REQ2`
but its actually the same. U shoul compare this
`REQ2 == 'http://myURL.com/get-request?uniqueId=12345'`
and i sure return will be `False`. So after this try to do
`print(REQ2.encode())`
Retuns will surprise u.
Thats because `response['uniqueId']` could return a list or a tuple or something else. Take sure that your `myId` is actually that what u need.
Good luck.